# Drop down menu with jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create the below mentioned kind of drop down menu for my existing server side menu item after the page loads.I hope it can be done by using jquery and css dynamically after the page loads.So can I have any support (without Twitter Bootstrap,Hence it's not using my project)?

I need this kind of feature.

[image]

For the existing this Server side menu.

[image]

HTML for existing menu

```
<div>
    <a onclick="eraseCookie('selectedTab')" href="http://localhost:6341/provider" title="Pet Care Professional">Pet Care Professional</a>
    <a onclick="eraseCookie('selectedTab')" href="http://localhost:6341/owner/company" title="Company">Company</a>
    <a onclick="eraseCookie('selectedTab')" href="http://localhost:6341/provider/tour" title="Product Tour">Product Tour</a>
    <a onclick="eraseCookie('selectedTab')" href="http://localhost:6341/owner/getinfo" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
    <a onclick="eraseCookie('selectedTab')" href="http://localhost:6341/" title="For Pet Owners">For Pet Owners</a>
    <a onclick="eraseCookie('selectedTab')" href="http://localhost:6341/owner/BlogFeeds" class="selected" title="Blog Feeds">Blog Feeds</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use simple Ul li with custom styling or any jquery plugin for that. http://www.projectseven.com/products/templates/pagepacks/dmm/affinity/menu-modes/index.htm#

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JW8SF/ if yes, you have to change the css styling. with modification to jquery

Comment: IS this a question on how to create and style a dropdown menu? What code can you show us?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I showed the code above.So For the 'selected' class I have to inject the html drop down feature dynamically,Hence my menu is server side one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Full [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5xdDk/embedded/result/) and demo with [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5xdDk/)

---

HTML markup

```
<dl class="dropdown"> 
    <dt><a href="#"><span>Blog Feeds</span></a></dt> 
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Feed 1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Feed 2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Feed 3</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

CSS code

```
 /* Optional */    
 body {
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
     font-size:0.75em;
     color:#000;
 }
 .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    position:relative;
 }
 .dropdown ul {
     margin: -1px 0 0 0;
 }
 .dropdown dd {
     position:relative;
    width: 170px;
 }
 .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited {
     text-decoration:none;
     outline:0;
 }
 .dropdown dt a {
     display:inline-block;
     color: #fff;
     min-width:172px;
     /* Gradient */
     background: #b7cb8f;
     background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
     base64, 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);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b7cb8f 0%, #77a230 100%);
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #b7cb8f), color-stop(100%, #77a230));
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b7cb8f 0%, #77a230 100%);
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b7cb8f 0%, #77a230 100%);
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b7cb8f 0%, #77a230 100%);
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #b7cb8f 0%, #77a230 100%);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b7cb8f', endColorstr='#77a230', GradientType=0);
 }
 .dropdown dt a span {
     cursor:pointer;
     display:block;
     padding:7px;
    color:#fff;
 }
 .dropdown dd ul {
     background:#fff; 
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     color:#666;
     display:none;
     left:0;
     padding:0;
     position:absolute;
     top:2px;
     width:auto;
     min-width:170px;
     list-style:none;
 }
 .dropdown span.value {
     display:none;
 }
 .dropdown dd ul li a {
     padding:5px;
     display:block;
    color: #666;
 }
 .dropdown dd ul li a:hover {
     background-color:#666;
    color: #fff;
 }
```

jQuery script

```
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function () {
     $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle();
 });
 $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function () {
     var text = $(this).html();
     $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
     $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
 });

 function getSelectedValue(id) {
     return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
 }
/* hide the dropdown menu by clicking any where - Optional */
 $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
     var $clicked = $(e.target);
     if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").slideUp();
 });
```

Hope that can help. Cheers and best of luck!

Comment: The thing here is,I cannot put static html for drop down menu.I have to inject those with jQuery. Can I do that ?

Comment: Would you make a fiddle with the markup you want and I will try to help you.

Comment: Actually you can use your example also.But cannot have 'HTML' section there (on fiddle).That content should inject through 'Javascript' section by using jQuery.